# How do I get the button dynamically programmed

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am new to the xamarin development. I am working on an app that adds the information from the SQLite database about the user. But my problem is it should dynamically create the button to show the user info after entering the info in the database.

I am able to get the information from the database and shows it on the activity but unable to create the button  as shown in the picture.

I am not sure if button will solve the issue or this is a list view.

[image: This image shows the exact step I want to perform. After pressing the + button I need to enter the data which I am able to do but how can I create the button eg: ID_Card or Whatever?]

Comment: You could use the listview to meet your requirements. You only need to update your data source

Answer (score 0):

This is a list view as it is dynamically populated and also has a separator.

You can create a custom cell with a image view, text view and a disclosure indicator.You can reuse this cell within the list view.

You can go through [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/Basics/) sample on List views.

Comment: Thanks pooja, I will give it a try and will see if it works for my case. Meanwhile, I was thinking to dynamically create a button which when clicked opens the activity with all the data populated from the database. Is this correct?

Comment: Adding a button may serve the purpose , but its very difficult to customize a button and its margins to give the look and feel of a list view . Especially a separator and in both iOS and android platform.I would suggest you to use a list view for this scenario

Comment: I am doing just android. Sure, I will try the list view